# How to list of all manager name of single employee

Tags: oracle

I need sql query for employee who is his/her manager's name and that manager is reporting to senior PM again that senior PM reporting to Delivery manager and that delivery manager reporting to Account Manager

I need hierarchy of employee reporting

```
                          5. Account Manager Name
                                   |
                          4. Delivery Manager Name
                                  |
                          3. Senior Project Manager Name
                                  |
                          2. Project Manager Name
                                  |
                          1. Employee
```

Comment: Could you please provide the related tables  and their column names? Or you just want an idea ?

Comment: I would like to know how to retrieve all the manager of the managers above of any employee until it reaches the Account Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your table having columns as Emp_ID, Emp_name and Manager_ID, You can try below query -

```
SELECT E1.Emp_name, E2.Emp_name
FROM EMPLOYEE E1
JOIN EMPLOYEE E2 ON E1.Manager_ID = E2.Emp_ID
START WITH E1.Emp_name = &Emp_name
CONNECT BY PRIOR E1.Manager_ID = E1.Emp_ID
WHERE LEVEL <= 5;
```

Since you have not posted the sample data, This query might not work.

Comment: My requirement is like A's manager is B & B's Manager is C and C's manager is D ............

Comment: Please post the expected result in the question. What exactly you want in tabular format?